# Forward all web traffic From wlan0 to eth0 in iptables

Tags: iptables

There's so many howtos on how to do this, and they're all slightly different, and they all give me a headache to try and decipher...

I have a Raspberry Pi that's "bridging" eth0 to wlan0 using dnsmasq and iptables. The wlan0 interface is the one connected to the main network and has Internet access. It gets a dynamic ip via DHCP on the network (10.0.1.xxx). The eth0 interface is set to a static ip address (192.168.220.1). The dnsmasq instance listens on eth0 and provides an ip address to anything that connects there (it always assigns the same ip address (192.168.1.2). IP forwarding is enabled in the kernel. My iptables rules looks like:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

This is all working fine. A client device on the eth0 port gets an ip address from the Pi's dnsmasq server, and the client device gains access to the internet through the Pi's wlan0 port.

Now my issue is that there's a web server running on port 80 of the "bridged" client device connected to eth0 and I need to access it from any other device on my network. Ideally, I'd like to just point my browser to the Pi's wlan0 IP address and have it act as the "bridged" client's web server. What iptable rules do I need to add to accomplish this?

Comment: Which one you call the "bridged" interface? Didn't understand.

Comment: eth0 is "bridged" (actually just forwarded) and is connected to a device that runs an http server on port 80. wlan0 is open to the outside world. I want the outside world to be able to talk to the http server that's connected to eth0. I don't even care about ip addresses, it's literally "any port 80 requests on wlan0 should be redirected to eth0"

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a destination network address translation rule to the PREROUTING chain with the following command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i wlan0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1:80
```

This means, for requests made to the destination port (--dport 80) of the Rpi's wlan0 interface/IP (-i wlan0) perform destination network address translation (DNAT) to forward the eth0 device's port 80. This translates ip traffic going both ways, so requests to 10.0.1.xxx:80 will be met with the web page served up by 192.168.2.1:80, working as intended.

Comment: I noticed he used "bridged" as well but seeing as he is trying to figure out routing with iptables I gave the relevant solution. 

The reality is that Raspberry Pi's don't support WDS, and therefore will never be a true layer 2 bridge for wireless to eth0 connected devices. The only two "bridge-like" solutions to get around this are in layer 3 and consist of this type of routing, DNAT, or Proxy ARP. Proxy ARP I've only got to work for internet connection, and don't understand fully with port listening, but if he want's to just access forwarded ports at the Pi's IP then NAT is the way to go.

Comment: I noticed that as well and will edit accordingly. I can tell you know more than I do on the subject, so to clarify would you call Proxy ARP a "bridge"? I have but that also feels like a misuse.

Comment: I've never considered proxy arp to be bridging; interesting thought.